# Communication between nodejs and tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, tampermonkey

This is more question about what is possible.

I am using tampermonkey to **scrape** table from the website I am using at work. It is helping me to manage tickets and stuff with it. At this moment I am using tampermoneky to show me numbers (like number of tickets, severieties, milestones etc.) on the same page. Currently I am working on separate page, as I can do more stuff on it, yet I have problem how I can communicate with that page.

I was thinking that I might send array every minute to node.js server, and once this array will be on node I can take it from there and start working on it.

Currently I am using json files, as I wanted to check if all the math is correct. Yet I need to do it manually. Is it possible that I could send this array to node server from tampermonkey?

Comment: Sure, have the userscript send the data to the server, and then the server can process it - the fact that this is a userscript rather than a native script tag makes very little difference

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was not sure if it is actually possible :D

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible.

First, make sure that the URL of your nodejs server is on the @connect list

```
// @connect      example.com
```

Second, make sure that you grant GM_xmlhttpRequest

```
// @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
```

After that, it would be pretty straightforward to send data to your server via a POST request:

```
const scrapedData = {
'item1': value1,
'item2': value2
}

GM_xmlhttpRequest ({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'example.com/api',
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  data: JSON.stringify(scrapedData) 
)}
```

In your nodejs server.js file (or whatever it is) include body-parser

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
```

And setup the route to handle the POST

```
app.post('/api', jsonParser, function (request, response) {
   const data = request.body
   console.log(data)
})
```

Of course, there's a lot you can do in terms of security, error handling and other things but that should get you started.